# How to return a table along with 2 varchar values from a Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, oracle

> Currently migrating Oracle database to Postgres and I have come across an use case where I am stuck.
> In Oracle I have a procedure which returns 3 values

1. The resultset from a SELECT query (This is an Oracle ref_cursor)
2. A message
3. A status

> This is the procedure in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ORA_TEST (
        I_EMP_ACTIVE IN VARCHAR2,
        O_RESULTSET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
        O_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR2
        O_STATUS OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
        V_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ACTIVE=I_EMP_ACTIVE;
                IF V_COUNT>0
                        OPEN O_RESULTSET FOR SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ACTIVE=I_EMP_ACTIVE;
                        O_STATUS := 'SUCCESS';
                        O_MESSAGE := 'Search Results found';
                ELSE
                        O_STATUS := 'FAILURE';
                        O_MESSAGE := 'No Search Results found';
                END IF;
END;
```

Now when I try to create this Procedure in Postgres as a Function, I can return the resultset as a TABLE or SETOF RECORD, but I am not able to return the O_MESSAGE and O_STATUS along with the resultset.

Please note that I cannot return the resultset using a Postgres ref_cursor (This is because we have some issues accessing ref_cursor from APIs, which is why we return the resultset using TABLE, SETOF RECORD or SETOF TYPE).

If there any way to achieve this type of resultset (with a TABLE as well as 2 varchar columns)?

Comment: Functions and procedures are two different things.  _Functions_ are supposed to return a single value, and used in a situation to assign that single value to something.

Comment: Yes I do understand that, but is there any way I can get the desired output? I dont have any issues with either Functions or Procedures, but AFAIK Postgres Procedures cannot have recordset of complex data types as OUT parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it like below...(I am not sure whether it will work with your API or not...)

```
create or replace function ORA_TEST(I_EMP_ACTIVE varchar) 
returns table(O_RESULTSET refcursor, O_MESSAGE varchar, O_STATUS varchar) as

$$
declare
V_COUNT int;
ref refcursor := 'mycursor';
begin
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ACTIVE=I_EMP_ACTIVE;
                IF V_COUNT>0 then 
                        OPEN ref FOR SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ACTIVE=I_EMP_ACTIVE;
                        O_STATUS := 'SUCCESS';
                        O_MESSAGE := 'Search Results found';
                ELSE
                        O_STATUS := 'FAILURE';
                        O_MESSAGE := 'No Search Results found';
                END IF;
                
return query

select ref, O_STATUS, O_MESSAGE;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

And call it like below:

```
BEGIN;
select * from ora_test('1');
FETCH ALL from "mycursor";
COMMIT;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ac8806e214ab106db5da6b4c08b84d78)

Comment: Yes, this would serve my purpose. The only problem is I cannot use refcursor in Postgres as there is a driver limitation at API end and they are not able to get the resultset in the proper format. Because of that reason I need to use either TABLE, SETOF RECORD or SETOF TYPE to return the resultset.

Comment: AFAIK that is not possible in postgres.